How to use raydium instruction
I have difficulty accessing raydium sdk, my purpose is to use raydium to create instructions and transactions. Hope everyone can help

Please narrow down your question to what exact code you have written so far, what exact error you are facing, and what type of transactions you want.

@AnishMukherjee i want create a instruction swap raydium
